# How to give an exception that search data returns error message in a loop when sending POST request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have IDs that each of them sending HTTP POST request in the website form but some of them return error and whole syntax stop returning the remained ID's output. The site has to radio bar that one is for corporate(L) and another one for individuals(P) in list named "tip". 
***Code supposed to check if the ID ('voen') is related to 'tip' L (for individuals) then when searching ID in the website the form of L (in the form_data list you can see the key named "tip" is referenced to tip list.***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Origin': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Referer': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT',
}

voens = [1700401281,
         4501313952,
         ]

tip = ['L',
       'P',
       ]

form_data = {
    'tip': tip,
    'voenOrName': 'V',
    'voen': voens,
    'name': '',
    'submit': '  Yoxla   ',
}


url = 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp'

for voen in voens:
    form_data['voen'] = voen
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers)
    s = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    sContent = s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]
    print(type(sContent))
    **if sContent:**
        outcome = sContent.get_text().strip()
        print(outcome)
    else:
        form_data['tip'] = tip[1]
        response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers)
        sContent = s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]
        print(sContent)
```

In the code above the "voens" dictionary there is one corporate and one individual IDs and in the code i write it like if the id is not corporate then check the another "tip" (P)
I thin the problem in the `if sContent:` line
ERROR MESSAGE: `sContent = s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]
IndexError: list index out of rang`

Comment: Can you reduce all this a bit, like a [mcve]? Point is that it's hard to tell what you want with all that code. Also, please use a bit of punctuation. Guessing where a sentence ends and another begins is not nice. As a new user, generally take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: i try to make i clear hope you understand it. Thanks for feedback

Comment: i need that if the code return error the `else` section on code have to be changed to `form_data['tip'] = tip[1]`

Comment: There's still code in there that isn't even syntactically right. Further, there is a loop, and it's unclear whether that loop is necessary to demonstrate the problem. If only one of the loop iterations causes a problem, then you need no loop for the [mcve]. Also, do you receive a response? If so, hard-code its content in your example. Even more, you have several chained (`foo.do_this().do_that()[42].bar())` calls. Which of them causes the problem? What are the arguments leading to the error? Lastly, please quote the whole error you receive as output (after the cleanup, of course).